# Serializing works but unserializing crashes

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to set up a save function in my HaxeFlixel game.

Some background: The object in question is an instance of `Player`, which extends `FlxSprite`. Save data is stored in an instance of a custom class I made for it. That instance is stored in a `StringMap` (the keys are save names), which is saved by serializing it to a variable in a `FlxSave`.

Creating the save data and writing it works fine. However, reading the save data back in crashes the game with the message "Invalid field: pixels". `pixels` is a field from FlxSprite, but it's not the first such field in the serialized string, so it's probably not that.

If it's useful, the declaration of that field is `y6:pixelsn` - that is:

- `y` begin a field, which is named...
- `6:` a string of length 6...
- `pixels` (the string)
- `n` null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this line of code](https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel/blob/7d6017b/flixel/FlxSprite.hx#L67) you can see that `pixels` is actually not a variable* at runtime. So the unserializer would crash when it tries to assign value to `pixels`. But more investigation is need on why the serializer serialized the `pixels` fields at the first place, because it shouldn't really exist at runtime.

Note*: the accessors of `pixels` are `(get, set)`, which makes `pixels` not a real property at runtime. Read more [here](http://haxe.org/manual/class-field-property-rules.html).

As a general rule, I don't recommend serializing a `FlxSprite` (or other complex objects) directly. Rather, you should extract the desired information (e.g. x/y position or hp, etc) and serialize only those.